# Get PHP values in AJAX to replace input field values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've created a **Custom Post Type** in Wordpress called **Location/Tour** and another one called **Itinerary**. In my CPT Itinerary, I have some **ACF custom fields** one of them is a **repeater field** that has **subfields** (Relationship field for the CPT Location/Tour, Title field, Description field).

I've created a button that should trigger an AJAX script which job is to get the values from the **CPT Location/Tour(Title and Description)** and
put them in my input **subfields(Title and Description)** in my **CPT Itinerary**.

I've created a PHP function that gets the values from the **CPT Location/Tour** and now I'm trying to run the PHP function using AJAX.

I was able to get the AJAX working and I get the values in my **console log** under ResponseText.

Now the part I'm struggling with. I need to set **each value** as a **separate variable** in JS so that I can replace the **input field values** with the new ones but unfortunately I don't know how.
I've tried almost everything and I think that I'm close to the answer but I'm missing something. :(

Here is my **post-value-loader.php**

```php
<?php
// LOAD DEFAULT VALUES FROM DEFAULT TOUR
add_action('wp_ajax_post_loader', 'post_loader');

function post_loader($field) {

  $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];

  $args = array(
    'p' => $post_id,
    'numberposts'=> -1,           // Fetch all posts...
    'post_type'=> 'location_tour',      // from the 'location_tour' CPT...
  );

  $location = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $location->have_posts() ) : while ( $location->have_posts() ) : $location->the_post();

        $title = the_field('title'); //The Title field value that we need
        $description = the_field('description'); //The Description field value that we need
        wp_reset_postdata();
      ?> 
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php add_action('acf/prepare_field/name=default_tour', 'post_loader'); ?>
<?php }


// BUTTON TO RUN AJAX
function my_acf_prepare_field($field) {
  echo '<div class="acf-field"><button type="submit" id="data_fetch" class="button acf-load-default-tour-values">Load default value</button></div>';
    return $field;
}
add_action('acf/prepare_field/name=default_tour', 'my_acf_prepare_field');


// ADD SCRIPT TO WORDPRESS ADMIN AJAX
function js_data_fetch() {
  wp_enqueue_script ("ajax-data-fetch", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/inc/assets/js/data-fetch.js", array('jquery')); 
  //the_ajax_script will use to print admin-ajaxurl in data-fetch.js
  wp_localize_script('ajax-data-fetch', 'the_ajax_script', array('ajaxurl' =>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
} 
add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts", "js_data_fetch");
?>
```

And here is my **data-fetch.js** (Note: I'm not a JS guy :( )

```js
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '#data_fetch', function( dohvati ){
    dohvati.preventDefault();

    var post_id = jQuery('.acf-row .selection .values ul li span').data('id'); // This takes the post ID from the selected Post(Location/Tour) in the Relationship field

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, //The URL that we set for the wordpress admin-ajax.php
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'post_loader', // This is the name of the php function
            post_id: post_id,
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
        },
    });
    jQuery("#acf-field_5cb991a9337db-row-0-field_5cbeabc041c8a").val(title); //This is replacing the title field - but the variables are missing
    jQuery("#acf-field_5cb991a9337db-row-0-field_5cbeab8f41c89").val(description); //This is replacing the description field - but the variables are missing
});
```

Also here are two images from the CPT Itinerary editor (https://imgur.com/kFImdpe) with the fields and my console log (https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0ZNt.jpg). Hope that this helps.
[image: CPT Itinerary]
[image: Console log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the data as JSON from post_loader function. I've cleaned up a little, but still, it's a mess.

```
// LOAD DEFAULT VALUES FROM DEFAULT TOUR
add_action('wp_ajax_post_loader', 'post_loader');

function post_loader() {

    $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];

    $args = array(
        'p' => $post_id,
        'numberposts'=> -1,           // Fetch all posts...
        'post_type'=> 'location_tour',      // from the 'location_tour' CPT...
    );

    $location = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $location->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $location->have_posts() ) : 
            $location->the_post();

            $title = the_field('title');
            $description = the_field('description');

            // You have to return data as json
            wp_send_json([
                'title' => $title,
                'description' => $description
            ]);

            //wp_reset_postdata();
        endwhile; 
    endif;  

    // Why do you need this inside this function?
    // add_action('acf/prepare_field/name=default_tour', 'post_loader');  

}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '#data_fetch', function( dohvati ){
    dohvati.preventDefault();

    var post_id = jQuery('.acf-row .selection .values ul li span').data('id'); // This takes the post ID from the selected Post(Location/Tour) in the Relationship field

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, //The URL that we set for the wordpress admin-ajax.php
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'post_loader', // This is the name of the php function
            post_id: post_id,
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)

            jQuery("#acf-field_5cb991a9337db-row-0-field_5cbeabc041c8a").val(data.title); //This is replacing the title field - but the variables are missing
            jQuery("#acf-field_5cb991a9337db-row-0-field_5cbeab8f41c89").val(data.description); //This is replacing the description field - but the variables are missing

        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
        },
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code works! I was able to solve the problem. Also, I've made a mistake while assigning the values to the variables. It should be $variable = get_field('field') not the_field('field') since get_field() is used to get the value and the_field() is used to print it out only.

Comment: ps. sorry for posting with the unnecessary code, I've cleaned it up now :D